# Triangle pattern of numbers in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

**Hi so I got a problem with a nested loop where the output must be like this:**

> ```
> 10
> 2030
> 304050
> 40506070
> 5060708090
> ```

but now I only know to do this which is:

```
10
1020
102030
10203040
1020304050
```

and this is my code currently:

```
def number(n):
    num = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        num = 10

        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            print(num, end="")
            num = num + 10
        print("\r")
n = 5
number(n)
```

**so how I change the code so that the output should be the same as the output needed?**

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you what number to use at the start of a line? Can you think of a way to use that rule to change the numbers that you print?

Comment: It is probably better to work this out yourself because this question is not about programming knowledge or technical difficulties, but problem-solving skills, which the question is trying to help you develop.

Comment: @Pandafiqz, keep an eye on the variable `num` and see where it's being changed. Debug (or simply dry run) the code and see when the value is updated and if it's being updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def contnum(n): 
    for i in range(0, n): 
        for j in range(0, i + 1): 
          print(i * 10 + 10, end="") 
          i = i + 1
        print("\r") 

n = 5
contnum(n)
```

Output:

```
10
2030
304050
40506070
5060708090
```

Answer (score 0):

change the first num to 10 and get rid of the second num.

```
def number(): 
  num = 10 
  for i in range(0, num): 
    for j in range(0, i + 1): 
    print(num, end="") 
    num = num + 10 
  print(" ") 
number()
```

You should try to shorten this code a little:)